# Get n records without using term...? (Lucene)

Tags: lucene

How can I get n records without using a term in lucene?

For example, fieldname = "id", and I want to get first 10 records of the id field without any term.

My code is:

```
    Dim qp As New QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30,"id", analyzer)
    Dim searcher = New IndexSearcher(directory, True)
    Dim q As Query = New TermQuery(New Term("id"))
    Dim hits As TopDocs = searcher.Search(q, 10)
```

Doesn't work.

When I change `Dim q As Query = New TermQuery(New Term("id"))` to `Dim q As Query = New TermQuery(New Term("id","10"))`, then it works, but I don't want to use any term query, I just want to get 10 records of id field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few possibilities, depending on what you are looking for.

- If you just want to get 10 documents from the index, use a [`MatchAllDocsQuery`](http://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/d5/d10/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_search_1_1_match_all_docs_query.html).
- If you only want to fetch documents that have a value for field = "id", you can use an open-ended [`TermRangeQuery`](http://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/dc/d5a/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_search_1_1_term_range_query.html).  If both the bottom and top value, passed to the range query, are `null` it will search for all documents with any (non-null) value for the field, such as: `new TermRangeQuery("id", null, null, true, true)`.
- If you just want to see all the terms in the id field, you can, instead of searching, fetch a `TermEnum` from the `IndexReader`, something like:

  ```
  TermEnum terms = reader.Terms(new Term("id"));
  while(terms.next()) {
      Term currentTerm = terms.term();
      if (!(currentTerm.field().equals())) {
          break;
      }
      String value = currentTerm.text();
      //Whatever else you need to do with the value
  }
  ```